# Convergence of Power Series at different value

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

[image]

<s>I know C is the correct answer using the Ratio Test.</s> (Wrong)

But why the series might not converge when x = 2?

I tried using the Direct Comparison Test and it seems that $a_n2^n > a_n(-1)^n$ and the series with x = 2 should converge as well since the larger series converges.

Comment: You are right, the series is convergent for $x=2$. If you're given a negatory answer, that answer is wrong.

Comment: C doesn't have to be. Consider $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n 2^n}$. You have $$ f(5) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n} $$ which is convergent (just not absolutely convergent) and $$ f(1) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} $$ which is divergent.

Comment: @AdamLatosiński By the way $a_n\ne \frac{(-1)^n}{n2^n}$ because we have $n=0$ in the summation.

Comment: @Peter Foreman Yeah you're right. But it's enough that $a_n$ is given by that fromula from some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question doesn't make any sense as C isn't even true if
$$a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)2^n}$$

Comment: Could you also explain why my ratio test doesn't work as well? Since lim n->∞ |(a_(n+1)/a_n) · (5-3)| < 1 as it converges,  thus lim n->∞ |(a_(n+1)/a_n) · (1-3)| < 1, so x = 1 also converges. Where did I do wrong?

Comment: If $a_{n+1}/a_n=1/2$ then the ratio test is inconclusive as the limit gives $1$ as a result, so the ratio test cannot be used to make any conclusion on the convergence.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I fully understood.